# angular broadcast not updating on second call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-broadcast

I have a controller which calls a service. Within the service, i perform a $rootScope.$broadcast which works perfectly on page load. However, when i call the service again, the $rootScope.$broadcast doesnt seem to be called.

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, myService) {

    myService.inititate($scope);

    $scope.Next = function () {
        myService.next($scope);
    };    
});
```

Service:

```
app.service("loginService", function ($http, $rootScope) {

    var counter = 0;

    var checkuser = function (scope) {
        //some code.....
        $rootScope.$broadcast('rcvrCast', counter + 1);
    }

    this.inititate = function (scope) {
        //some code.....
        checkuser(scope);
    };

    this.next = function (scope) {
        //some code.....
        checkuser(scope);
    };
);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on("rcvrCast", function(event, val) {
                scope.myValue = val;
            });
        },
        template:
            '<section>' +
                '<p>{{myValue}}</p>' +                        
            '</section>'
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="ParentController">

    <section my-directive></section>

    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

The `index.html` page loads `MyController` controller.

On page load, the `$broadcast` called from `this.inititate` is successfully being called and `{{myValue}}` displays as 1.

However, on click on my button which has `ng-click="Next()"`, although the service is being called again, `{{myValue}}` is still showing as 1, rather than 1 + 1 = 2.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not counting with the counter.
Try using `++counter` instead of `counter+1`

```
app.service("loginService", function ($http, $rootScope) {

    var counter = 0;

    var checkuser = function (scope) {
        //some code.....
        $rootScope.$broadcast('rcvrCast', ++counter);
    }

    this.inititate = function (scope) {
        //some code.....
        checkuser(scope);
    };

    this.next = function (scope) {
        //some code.....
        checkuser(scope);
    };
);
```